# Which SQL Availability Group Replica should the AG cluster name connect to in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

My AGs are all healthy, different ones on different clusters, all SQL 2019.

When I connect to the cluster name from SSMS, should I expect it to connect to the current primary replica? If so, any ideas why mine is connecting to a particular replica regardless of whether or not it is primary? Is that an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

> When I connect to the cluster name from SSMS, should I expect it to connect to the current primary replica?

You shouldn't have any inclination that this would, at all, work. Why? Because the cluster name has nothing to do with nor is itself an Availability Group.

> If so, any ideas why mine is connecting to a particular replica regardless of whether or not it is primary?

Because that's the node that owns the core cluster resources and you *happen* to have an instance of SQL Server on that very node which is listening on 1433 and you also happen to have a login which can access it.

> Is that an expected behaviour?

Yes.

Comment: thank you for your always helpful contributions, much appreciated. Understood. The trouble I'm trying to troubleshoot however is that the application connects to one replica when it is primary, but not to the other replica when it is primary. It's like when the failover happens to the other replica, the failover appears not to be completely done? Hence it appears to still be seen by the application as secondary and so does not connect. Please do you have any thoughts on what to check? thank you.

Comment: @PTL_SQL For one you need to create a use a listener. If the setup it multisubnet then you should use multisubnetfailover. If it's the same subnet and it isn't working then you'll need to investigate the use of garp. If it's in the cloud, you need to follow whatever weird cloud specific items they require.

Comment: thanks again. The AGs are all correct, listeners in place, AG healthy, failovers happen successfully as far as we can see in SSMS. However, we are just trying to troubleshoot the described weird behaviour when the application connects to the cluster name as opposed to the name of either of the nodes. Hence my try to understand what the expected behaviour is when I connect to the cluster name, either node name, listener name. I'd appreciate if could share the expected behaviour with me please. If I connect to cluster name or listener, should I expect it to connect to the primary?

Comment: You should always connect to the listener name.

Comment: thank you. Will try that, much appreciated.